# JSON array php mysql

Tags: json, php

пытаюсь вытащить все данные таблицы и сгенерировать правильно json массив из них - не получается.

```
    $fetch = mysql_query("SELECT name,login,auto,coord1,coord2, country, region, oblast, town, street,house, age,pol,phone FROM users"); 
    $json = array();
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($fetch)){
        $json[] = $r;
    }
```

и получается вот такое:

```
        "0": "",
        "1": "hgf",
        "2": "???",
        "3": "50.4408366",
        "4": "30.4444274",
        "5": "???",
        "6": "??????",
        "7": "2130968630",
        "8": "0",
        "9": "",
        "10": "",
        "11": "????",
        "12": "",
        "13": "???????",
        "14": "?????",
        "15": "",
        "16": "",
        "17": "1",
        "18": "",
        "19": "930773225",
        "region": "",
        "phone": "930773225",
        "coord1": "50.4408366",
        "coord2": "30.4444274",
        "start_point": "",
        "street": "",
        "house": "",
        "gosnumber": "???",
        "pol": "",
        "age": "1",
        "name": "",
        "seats": "0",
        "login": "hgf",
        "auto_model": "??????",
        "end_point": "",
        "oblast": "???????",
        "country": "????",
        "color": "2130968630",
        "auto": "???",
        "town": "?????"
```

почему-то дублируются поля, цифер не должно быть. я никогда пхп не учил поэтому не совсем понимаю принципа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратимся к [документации](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php).
По умолчанию, тип выдаваемых данных он ассоциативный и обычный массив: MYSQL_BOTH. Вам нужно установить флаг, чтобы был ассоциативный массив: MYSQL_ASSOC. Должно помочь.

Comment: благодарю) это решило проблему)